# Is there a list of generic help comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, help-center

Is there a list of generic comments available to users with higher rep to use in instances of reviewing and general site moderation?

I've seen some users re-use the same moderation comments (e.g., concerning off-topic, references, homework, etc.). Are they re-using their own general comments, or are these compiled somewhere?

It'd be nice to not have to retype some frequent comments all the time...

Comment: Related and possible duplicate of https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3275/what-are-some-good-informative-comments-i-can-leave-for-new-users

Comment: Looks like the thing is now also under scope of [Greeting bot](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/redesigning-biology-stack-exchange/3639#3639) proposal.

Answer (score 5):

In the review queue some verdicts end up with being accompanied by an automated comment, for example a delete vote on an answer. I can't find a good example online (many of mine indeed got deleted :-) but it states:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have
>   sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post;
>   instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the
>   asker. - From Review – X

And that one has all the fancy links included.

Otherwise, I often write a customized response myself and then you can decide to include the links to the relevant page of the [**help center**](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help). The page on [**what topics should I avoid asking**](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) is one I often cite and link, for example.

I have to add that I only go through the hassle of linking pages and explaining when I believe OP is serious about it. Many OPs appearing in the 'First Questions' review queue are of the hit-and-run type and I, personally, often don't even bother to write an extensive help comment [anymore! -- I reviewed 1.7k first-posts and at times I'm getting a bit tired of those volatile users]. I really appreciate new energetic members that are putting time and effort in helping potential new users on their way on this fascinating site. We were in Beta mode not so long ago and we should keep the spirits up.

Comment: Great, thanks. Maybe we could create a community meta answer (to this question perhaps) with a bunch of generalized comments (with embedded links) for others to utilize for easier moderation?? A bit of consistency would be good too! Also, not being too far removed from being a new user myself, I understand the frustrations of not knowing exactly what "you did wrong". So consistent commenting would help alleviate that feeling for (yes you're right only some) new users. A general community list of comments to easily copy/paste from would help make this easier I think...

Comment: Oooh. Looks like this list [already exists](http://meta.biology.stackexchange.com/q/3275/16866)!