# Why so mean? Not a good first impressiong

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

So I just asked this question:

[How does a chicken egg go from one cell to many](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113513/how-does-a-chicken-egg-go-from-one-cell-to-many)

And rather than a response like "I know all about this, let me explain it to you"  I just got downvoted, and then ridiculed for even asking the question.  And I still don't have an answer!  The guy that downvoted and closed the question clearly doesn't know, and just posted links to other questions that shed some light, but don't answer the question.

So as a newby, I'm not likely to come back to Biology stack to ask more questions or interact.  But having been involved in other stacks over the years and met with much nicer responses, I felt it's worth pointing out that this is really not the best attitude to have.

The guy who responded has a diamond so is clearly influential here.

Not a cool welcome.

### Edit:

In response to the comment:
"One of the linked duplicates explains the whole egg is not an entire cell. The other explains that the yolk is not an entire cell, either. Did you read them?"

Yes, I've read them, but the point here is, in comparison with more welcoming sites, no effort was made to answer the question.  The question was voted for close without detailed explanation how those other questions relate.  There was no explanation WHY those help answer the question.  They are clearly not direct duplicates, since this question is asking about how the egg cell divides, not what the egg IS.  Granted they are very helpful in deducing the answer, but not themselves an answer.  For example, none of them state WHEN mitosis begins.

Perhaps a better response, even when there are related questions around, is to answer the question, and link to other questions that are similar.

### Edit 2

I should probably vote to close this.  The meaness of this site is already well covered here:

[What does "Be Nice" *mean* to you?](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4277/77803)

I'm out of here.  Deleted my Biology stack profile.  Best of luck.

Comment: One of the linked duplicates explains the whole egg is not an entire cell. The other explains that the yolk is not an entire cell, either. Did you read them?

Answer (score 3):

I was not involved in this question in any way, as I know little about organismal biology and embryology. However, like the poster, I have used the privilege earned on one site (SE Biology) to gain 100 credits when posting on other sites where I am no expert (e.g. SE French). These credits are given because SE assumes that you know what is the expected behaviour on SE sites. I have always been very careful to respect these sites, but I am afraid that this question (and the poster’s original question) does not do this.

Expected behaviour includes:

- Don’t bad-mouth the site you are guest on. By all means say that you felt it ‘unwelcoming’ — which is an optional extra in life. But the use of the word ‘mean’ implies a moral criticism of individuals, which is neither ‘nice’ nor likely to endear you to members on the site.
- Read the Tour to find out what the constituency of a site is, what sort of topics are allowable, and what is expected of a question. This site is a serious academic site for “biology researchers, academics, and students”, which is why we expect reputable sources for statements.  “We are always told” does not cut it, nor does quirkyscience.com. Pointing this out is *not* ridiculing you.
- Don’t attack the moderators. We would expect that you are aware of the role of the “guys with the diamond”, the experience they have, and the amount of work they put in to trying to maintain the standards of the site. If you don’t agree with their decisions, either ask nicely why (here on Meta) or just shrug your shoulders and say nothing. I don’t always agree with their actions — many of my comments have been removed over the years — but I have only ever challenged their actions (or actually inaction) when I was personally abused by another list member, and I did that through the official complaints procedure, not in public.